# Shape of numpy array is changing while saving the data

Tags: python, numpy, saving-data

I've defined the following arrays:

```
self._list = np.zeros((1, 180))
```

in the **init** method of a class

and

```
lidar_data = np.zeros((1, 180))
```

in the **call** method of the same class

**call** method is called indefinitely.

I would like to save the data from the lidar sensor and analyze it for which I'm doing,

```
self._list = np.vstack((self._list, lidar_data[None, :]))
```

When I print the `lidar_data.shape`, it comes to be (1, 180) when

```
self._list = np.vstack((self._list, lidar_data[None, :]))
```

is commented out, but when it is not commented,

`lidar_data.shape` comes out to be (1, 0)

and because of this I'm unable to save the data and get the following error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Why is the value of `lidar_data.shape` changing?
What is better way of saving the data than this?

EDIT:

Though `lidar_data` has the shape of (1, 180) initially, after the data is taken it's shape is `(180, )` so by doing `lidar_data[None, :]` I get the shape to be (1, 180).

EDIT 2:

```
lidar_data = np.zeros((1, 180))
lidar_data = controller.sensor(33).getMeasurements()
lidar_data = np.array(lidar_data) #shape (180, )
lidar_data = lidar_data[None, :]  #shape (1, 180)


print 'self._list: ', self._list.shape #shape (1, 180)
print 'lidar_data: ', lidar_data.shape #shape(1, 180)
#self._list = np.vstack((self._list, lidar_data))


This works fine,and the output is


self._list:  (1, 180)
lidar_data:  (1, 180)


the problem arises when

print 'self._list: ', self._list.shape
print 'lidar_data: ', lidar_data.shape
self._list = np.vstack((self._list, lidar_data))
```

when I run the script, I get the following errors,

```
self._list:  (1, 180)
lidar_data:  (1, 0)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from `vstack`ing two arrays with shape (1, 180) and (1,0)?

Comment: Even before stacking why is the size of `lidar_data` changing automatically? Read the description of the problem

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see why the shape changes, it seems you've skipped some codes? You'd better give a short example which can reproduce your problem.